# Applescript : Remove specific items from plist dock using the provided persistent apps array

Tags: arrays, macos, applescript, plist, dock

Hello I am trying to remove and add a couple of specific apps from the default dock using a script.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist"
        set value of property list item "Firefox.app" to null
    end tell
end tell
```

this is what i have which throws an error

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t set property list item \"Firefox.app\" of property list file \"/Users/immam.m/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist\" to null." number -10006 from property list item "Firefox.app" of property list file "/Users/immam.m/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist" to null
```

I also wanted to figure out a way to add apps to the array so it shows on the dock upon KIllall command.

Sorry if this is an easy process, pretty new to mac and applescript.
Help is appreciated

Comment: Have a look at: [Working with Property List Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithPropertyListFiles.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using a different method

```
do shell script "
    
    defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array 
    
    
    '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>System/Applications/System Preferences.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'  

.. keep adding to the array

;
Killall Dock;"
```